# Regex: get all characters after numbers

Tags: python, regex

I have list of strings, for example like this:

```
ABC-2345
GGYD3495
EPF_4739
RTY-5678A
QTG138910BC
```

How can I get:
"2345", 
"3495", 
"4739",
"5678A",
"138910BC"
?

Basically I want to get all characters starting from the number for each string.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/1qsFrk/1

Comment: Are there only numbers at the end or there could be other characters?

Comment: @Predicate can be other characters and can be different length. I edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code which will return the further string when it finds 1st number:

```
import re

inp_string = "QTG138910BC"
groups_out = re.search(r'([A-Za-z-_]+)([A-Za-z0-9]+)', inp_string)
print groups_out.groups()  # ('QTG', '138910BC')
print (groups_out.group(2))
```

***Output:***

```
138910BC
```

***Link:***

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

it depends if there are only 4 digits like you proposed, then you can use the solution of 0m3r:

```
([0-9]{4})
or
[0-9]+  // if number of characters varies
```

Or when there could be other characters as well, then this:

```
\d\w*\b
```

\d starts with a digit. \w* takes all characters after the digit, \b looks for a word boundary, basically matching to the end of the word

https://regex101.com/r/KTtinh/1

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
import re
lst = ['ABC-2345', 'GGYD3495', 'EPF_4739', 'RTY-5678A', 'QTG138910BC']
lst = [re.sub(r'^[^0-9]*', '', l) for l in lst]
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['2345', '3495', '4739', '5678A', '138910BC']
```

The regex function `re.sub(r'^[^0-9]*', '', l)` removes non-digit characters starting at the beginning of `l`.

Comment: Do not create variables called `list`. `list` is a built-in list constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You want any number of non-digits (`'\D*'`), followed by at least one digit (`'(.*\d.*)'`):

```
import re
strings = ['ABC-2345', 'GGYD3495', 'EPF_4739', 'RTY-5678A', 'QTG138910BC']

[re.findall(r'\D*(.*\d.*)', s)[0] for s in strings]
#['2345', '3495', '4739', '138910BC']
```

For each string, `findall` returns a list of matching fragments. Since you have only one matching fragmentin each string, `[0]` selects the first item from the one-item list.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do **(\d)+**, it will fetch all the digits from the strings.

[image]